# Android issue with height when EditText is inserted dynamically

Tags: android, insert, height, android-edittext

I'm working on an Android application and I have some problems that I can't solve.

In xml, I have a `RelativeLayout` with one `EditText`, and dynamically I have to insert one or two `EditText` more, depending on a variable value.

**Problem**

The problem is that when I insert one `EditText` above the first one (the one declared in xml), it gets so much height, I can't see the end of it, and I can't understand why it happens.

Here is my code up to date:

**activity.xml**

```
<!-- Some other layouts -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutLectura1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/linearLayoutMensajeLectura"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextLectura1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/introducir_lectura"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize" />

</RelativeLayout>
<!-- More layouts -->
```

**Activity.java**

```
if(lecturas > 1) {
    // Have to insert lecturas-1 EditText
    RelativeLayout parentLayout = (RelativeLayout) 
    findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutLectura1);
    for(int lectura = 2; lectura < lecturas; lectura++) {
        EditText editTextLectura = new EditText(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        if(lectura == 2) {
            //Insert below the one created in xml
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.editTextLectura1);
        } else {
            //Insert below the one created in previous iteration
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lectura-1);
        }
        editTextLectura.setLayoutParams(params);
        editTextLectura.setId(lectura);
        editTextLectura.setHint(R.string.introducir_lectura);
        editTextLectura.setTextSize(R.dimen.textSize);
        //Add to layout
        parentLayout.addView(editTextLectura);
    }
}
```

Can you help me finding the problem? `EditText` created in xml is seen correctly, and the one created by code is set in correct place.

Comment: it's confusing to have a relativeLayout with an id like this : @+id/linearLayoutLectura1

Comment: yes, before I had a `LinearLayout` and when I changed it to `RelativeLayout` I forgot to change id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution! I use:

```
editTextLectura.setTextSize(R.dimen.textSize);
```

`textSize` is declared in dimen file:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Other dimen -->
    <dimen name="textSize">15dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

and, as you can see, I use it in xml, too, and it runs ok:

```
<EditText ...
    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize" />
```

I don't know why but if I put `15dp` instead of `R.dimen.textSize` on my `Activity` code, it is ok.

I'll be pleased if anyone can explain that.

Comment: It is also happening to me!

Comment: The problem is you didn't give it the size, but the id of the size resources; that is, you should have `editTextLectura.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textSize));`